# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape

Tags: python, deep-learning

I have this code that reshapes my image but it yields an error when I get to it: `Value Error: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 3072)`. 
I used modules `tensorflow`, `keras`, and `cv2`.

It looks like my input or output is incorrect or I have to input 4 dimensions.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
#from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import load_model
import argparse
import pickle
import cv2
import os
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
lb = LabelBinarizer()
f = open("simple_multiclass_classifcation_lb.pickle", "wb")
f.write(pickle.dumps(lb))
f.close()

test_image_path = r"E:\classification\test\test\pan26.jpg"

model_path = r"PanModel.model.h5"

label_binarizer_path = "E:\API\simple_multiclass_classifcation_lb.pickle"

image = cv2.imread(test_image_path)
output = image.copy()
image = cv2.resize(image, (32,32))

 #scale the pixel values to [0, 1]
image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
image = image.flatten()
print ("image after flattening",len(image))
image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0]))
print ("image--reshape",image.shape)

# load the model and label binarizer
print("[INFO] loading network and label binarizer...")
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('PanModel.model.h5')
#model = load_model("PanModel.model.h5")
lb = pickle.loads(open(label_binarizer_path, "rb").read())

# make a prediction on the image
print (image.shape)
preds = model.predict(image)

# find the class label index with the largest corresponding
# probability
print ("preds.argmax(axis=1)",preds.argmax(axis=1))
i = preds.argmax(axis=1)[0]
print (i)
label = lb.classes_[i]
# draw the class label + probability on the output image
text = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, preds[0][i] * 100)
cv2.putText(output, text, (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Image", output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 3072)
```

Can you help spot the error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reshape your input array to `(number_images, image_width, image_height, channels)`

Comment: try deleting `image = image.flatten()` and `image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0]))` and print the resulting shape if it still doesn't work.

Comment: i get this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modeltest.py", line 39, in <module>
    image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0]))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3072 into shape (1,1)`

Comment: Why would you want to reshape your image to this shape? Did you read my answer?

Comment: i am testing my image with model i have builted

Comment: Your model expects a specific shape for your input image, to be more accurate, it expects the shape I specified in my answer

Comment: will you please change my code according to your answer?

Comment: I alreay told you to delete `image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0]))`...

Comment: i delete it but same problem

Comment: How do you get this tracelog `Traceback (most recent call last): File "modeltest.py", line 39, in <module> image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0])) ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3072 into shape (1,1)` after having deleted the line included in the tracelog?

Comment: after deleting this i got this `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have shape (360, 360, 3) but got array with shape (32, 32, 3)
`

Comment: The issue seems to come from your call `image = cv2.resize(image, (32,32))`, try deleting this line

Comment: now i got this error `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (151470, 1)` on line `    preds = model.predict(image)`

Comment: What about not deleting the last line but using `image = cv2.resize(image, (360, 360))` instead?

Comment: then i got this error `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have shape (360, 360, 3) but got array with shape (32, 32, 3)`

Comment: Did you put the good shape (`(360, 360)`) in your `resize` call?

Comment: yes after add `(360,360)` i got this `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (388800, 1)`

Comment: Final step: use `image = image.reshape((-1, 360, 360, 3))`

Answer (score 0):

first remove

```
image = image.flatten()
```

and then change

```
image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0]))
```

to

```
image = image.reshape((1, 32,32,3))
```

Comment: this error `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have shape (360, 360, 3) but got array with shape (32, 32, 3)`

Comment: change image = cv2.resize(image, (32,32)) to image = cv2.resize(image, (360,360)) and change image = image.reshape((1, 32,32,3)) to image = image.reshape((1, 360,360,3))

Comment: what is this error `AttributeError: 'LabelBinarizer' object has no attribute 'classes_'
`